# Get link from A1 Cell and Put it to another cell with predefined text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to take a link from for example: Page2 - C1 cell and want to put it to Page1 - A1 cell but when the link from Page2 comes, it shouldn't look like only https://link.com but it should be like [LINK](https://link.com) I mean the link should be applied to my predefined text

I tried everything like hyperlink and etc. but its not happening

Comment: **[HYPERLINK()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hyperlink-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f)** is needed here! It has a dedicated parameter for a **[friendly_name]** which is optional and can be used. Here is the syntax **=HYPERLINK(link_location, [friendly_name])**

Comment: can you show me an example formula please? I tried different variations of hyperlink formula and couldn't be successful

Comment: Look here: **[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/gallery/0g9Oax7)** I have used this in cell `C1` of `Sheet2` **[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel?tab=Newest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel?tab=Newest)** and named as **[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel?tab=Newest)** in cell `A1` of `Sheet1` You can obviously use any name!